# VB getting the last 3 digit number in textbox

Tags: excel, vba

i have 16textbox and one command button for my userform and the textbox 1 are the one that i use to search for the data and display it from other textbox.

my question is.

it is possible for textbox1 to search only the last 3 digit number instead of 8 digit? wish can some answer my question.

thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is. Use `Right` function eg.

```
sub test()

Dim R3 as String, s as String

s = "123-234-456"
R3 = Right(s,3)

End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: where should i put the code sir ? i have no idea sorry im just a newbie hehe

Comment: That depends on what your code is. You didn't post anything.

Comment: can i sen to you my code for command button sir so you can see it ..sorry for taking so much of your time but i really need a help my deadline of my project was these  coming friday

Comment: What you need to do is to post it in your question, this way more people will be able to help you.

Comment: Please also `Dim s as String` :)